# Can I get repeated Contest Ribbons?

Tags: pokemon-fourth-generation, pokemon-third-generation

I was looking at [the list of ribbons on Pokémon games](https://www.serebii.net/games/ribbons.shtml), but I see there are some 'repeated' ribbons, like the 'Beauty Ribbon' awarded in Generation III and IV games.

My question is, if I get a Pokémon on Gen III with that ribbon, then I transfer it to Gen IV, and gain that ribbon again on a contest (on a DPPt game for example) will it appear as a brand new ribbon, next to the old one from Gen III, or will just be the same?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There was a guy, Mockturne, who achieved to get every existing ribbon on his Delibird named Oswald.

Here is the [complete story](https://www.reddit.com/r/pokemon/comments/5wh7dz/oswalds_ribbon_guide_updated_for_alola/) updated to Alola, so according to his witness you actually get a new ribbon.